# Do I have to manually reset inner shared_ptrs (shared_ptrs as members of a class)

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, reset

Lets say I have:

```
class InnerClass { };

class MyClass {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<InnerClass> innerSharedPtr;
};

void main() {
    std::shared_ptr<MyClass> mrSharedPtr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
}
```

If I want to reset mrSharedPtr, do I need to reset it's shared_ptr members?

```
mrSharedPtr->innerSharedPtr.reset();
mrSharedPtr.reset();
```

If I mrSharedPtr.reset(), it reduces reference count to 0, but does that reduce innerSharedPtr to 0? if not does that mean innerSharedPtr remains in memory?

There's no way to check the reference count after resetting

Comment: No you do not, when your MyClass goes out of scope it will destruct all its members too.  And the destructor of std::shared_ptr will manage refcounts and those reach 0 then also the Innerclass is destroyed.

Comment: My real question is do you really need nested shared ownership it is very rare to find that in a design (not impossible just rare)

Comment: You don't need to do anything for any properly-designed C++ types in your destructor when using them as members. The exceptions are very rare. It is one of C++'s core philosophies that objects should clear up their resources once their own lifetime ends automatically. When you write your own classes they should very rarely have a user-defined constructor at all. That's only necessary when your class specifically is managing a resource manually (e.g. using memory allocated with `new`).

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks, I don't need it but it's from a codebase I'm working with, made 10 years ago

Comment: Have you ever heard about RAII, if not read this [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Answer (score 0):

`std::shared_ptr::reset` (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset)):

> If `*this` already owns an object and it is the last `shared_ptr` owning it, the object is destroyed through the owned deleter.

When the `MyClass` instance is destroyed, part of that is to destroy the `innerSharedPtr` member. When this `shared_ptr` was the last shared pointer to that `InnerClass`, that instance will be destroyed as well.

There is no need to call `mrSharedPtr->innerSharedPtr.reset();` before `mrSharedPtr.reset();`.